# How to know what System drive is stored on a VMWare HardDrive with powerCli to append it

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I have a VM with lot of disk (C: D: E: F: G: H: I: J: ...) with same size

I need to append One with the command `Set-HardDrive` but how to determinate what VMWareDrive it is

EDIT
I get UUID with WMI

```
$wmidisk = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $ComputerName
$UUID_OS = $wmidisk.SerialNumber
```

I have the same UUID in VMWare

```
$Device_VMWare = (get-vm $ComputerName | get-view).Config.Hardware.Device | ?{$_.Backing.Uuid}
$UUID_VMWare = ($Device_VMWare.backing.uuid).replace('-','')
```

but I lack the correspondence with the disc

Comment: as in how do you know what virtual disk is associated to what drive letter?

Comment: i don't know but i need it

Comment: Do you have them attached as SCSI?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SCSI ID to identify the correct drive. Check this [blog post](http://www.van-lieshout.com/2009/12/match-vm-and-windows-harddisks-using-powercli/), you might can reuse some code.